# Android - DeleteIntent, how to use?

Tags: android, notifications, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I currently have a notification in my Android application that has a PendingIntent so that when it is clicked an activity is opened.

I currently keep a counter for the notification, similar to the native missed calls notification.

I can reset this counter to 0 when the notification is clicked.

I also want to reset the counter to 0 when the user selects the "Clear all notifications" button. I have done a search and seen the way to do this is to use the DeleteIntent.

But I cant figure out how to use this alongside my PendingIntent, can anyone help me out?

Comment: How do you reset the counter to 0 when the notification is clicked?  I am using an int variable in SharedPreferences as my counter and can't figure out how to reset when the user clicks on the Notification dropdown shade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a broadcast or service `PendingIntent`, pointing to a `BroadcastReceiver` or `IntentService` that will reset your counter, and associate that `PendingIntent` with your `Notification` via `deleteIntent`.